# How to remove the layer name in a legend in CARTO?

Tags: carto

Is it possible to remove the layer name within the legend (bezirke & berlin_pts). I tried all the obvious ways, but could not manage it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround: change the layer name to just a "white space".

Comment: Sadly that does only work for a second. When I go back into the map overview and click on my test_map, the layer-names are back, despite they don't have a layer name anymore.

Comment: You are right. Let me report it (disclaimer: I am a Solutions Engineer at CARTO). I will update my answer with their feedback.

Comment: thx, very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm looking to do the same. Was a solution to this problem ever found?

Comment: @AndreasK, KristenG. Thanks for your patience. The issue has been solved in this [PR](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/pull/12526). You can check my answer now as solved.

Comment: Wow, thx, I'll check that.